# Solving $ab\equiv d \pmod c $ knowing $b, c \text{ and }d.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Do you know if it's possible to solve the equation :

$$ab\equiv d \pmod c $$

knowing $b, c \text{ and }d?$

It's been a while I'm looking for answer but I can't find nothing.

Could you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It is possible if $b$ is a unit mod. $c$, i.e. if $b$ and $c$ are coprime. In other cases there are conditions to check on, $c$ and $d$.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with differential equations.

Comment: And of course the answer is only determined mod $c$.

Comment: A silly, but correct thing to do: If you know $b$, $c$, and $d$, then there are only $c$ values of $a$ to try. Plug these into a computer and see when $(ab - d) \bmod c = 0$. This isn't an exact form, of course, but it works.

Comment: $bx\equiv d \pmod c\iff bx-d=yc$ linear equation of two unknowns which infinitely many solutions in general except when .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if and only if $\gcd(b,c)$ divides $d$ (we have to use *Bézout's identity* to prove this). In particular it's always possible if $\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Indeed, let $\delta=\gcd(b,c)$. We have a Bézout's relation $\; ub+vc=\delta$ for some $u,v\in\bf Z$.

Now we want a relation $\; ab+kc=d$ for some $k\in\bf Z$. Setting $\;b_1=\dfrac bδ$, $\;c_1=\dfrac cδ$, $b_1$ and $c_1$ are coprime since $ub_1+vc_1=1$, and the equation can be rewritten as
$$ab+kc=(ab_1+kc_1)δ=d,$$
so $δ$ divides d. Conversely, if $δ$ divides $d$: $d_1= \dfrac dδ̓$, and we solve
$\;ab_1+kc_1=d_1$, we also have, multiplying both sides by $δ$, $\;ab+kc=d$.

The the only problem is how to solve the congruence when $b$ and $c$ are coprime. But that is easy thanks to *Bézout*; the extended Euclidean algorithm produces the coefficients of a Bézout's relation between $b$ and $c$: $\;ub+vc=1$, so $u$ is the inverse of $b\bmod c$, and
$$ba\equiv d\mod c\iff uba\equiv ud\mod c\iff a\equiv ud\mod c.$$

̓̓̓̓

Answer (score 0):

Citing [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse):

> As with the analogous operation on the real numbers, a fundamental use
>   of this operation is in solving, when possible, linear congruences of
>   the form,
>
> $a x \equiv b \pmod m $ .

Answer (score 0):

We need $\gcd (b,c)\mid d$.  See [the following](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) .